# How to share share variable between two components without service

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have 2 components:

```
export class A implements OnInit {
.
.
.
}
```

```
export class B implements OnInit {
@Component({
  selector: 'app-center-pictures',
  templateUrl: 'center-pictures.component.html',
  providers: [PictureService],
  styleUrls: ['center-pictures.component.css']
})
   pictures: PictureData[];
   center: Center;
   .
   .
   .
```

The template of A contains a nb-tab (Nebular)

```html
 <nb-tab tabTitle="Photos"
                    badgeText="..."
                    badgePosition="top right"
                    badgeStatus="info">
                    <div class="separator">
                        <app-center-pictures [center]="center"></app-center-pictures>
                      </div>
            </nb-tab>
```

I want `badgeText` to be equal to `pictures.length` but i don't have a direct access to it because the template is the template of A and not B

Comment: What is the relationship between A & B ? And most of the time, component intercations goes through a service, so any particular reason as to not use one ?

Comment: The component A contains the component B in its template `<app-center-pictures [center]="center"></app-center-pictures>
`

Comment: The service returns all the pictures : `return this.http.get<PictureData[]>`, this call is already done by the component B. So `<app-center-pictures [center]="center"></app-center-pictures>` displays the pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a "variable reference" -in this case I called "centerPictures". Then you can use any variable public of your component (I supouse you store the data received in a variable called "pictures").

```
 <nb-tab tabTitle="Photos"
        badgeText="centerPictures?.pictures?.length"
        badgePosition="top right"
        badgeStatus="info">
        <div class="separator">
            <app-center-pictures #centerPictures [center]="center">
            </app-center-pictures>
        </div>
</nb-tab>
```

**Update** (and disclamer) in the code before, I talk about put `#centerPictures="CenterPicturesComponent"`, It's wrong, the use of `#templateReference="directive"` it's useful if the directive is not the own component. The clasic is when in a input we write `#templateReference="ngModel"`, and then we use the methos and properties of a ngModel. Apologies for inconvenience

Comment: it says `There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "CenterPicturesComponent"`

Comment: it's the **name of the class** of your component app-center-pictures, you need import in parent

Comment: parent: A, child: CenterPicturesComponent right ? I imported CenterPicturesComponent in A but I still got this error.

Comment: @Eliseo - Can't you just define `#centerPictures` by itself? It should refer to the component instance by default.

Comment: Ok, fixed :  `<app-center-pictures #centerPictures [center]="center">`

Comment: "CenterPricesComponent" wasn't necessary

Comment: great!!, and thanks for the aclaration, I just update the answer